# Truncating /r and returns Failed opening required

Tags: php

I haven't had an issue (that I'm aware of) of including PHP files in a different directory. What is this PEAR and why is it trying to be included? Why is it printing `\scripts equests` and not `scripts\requests`

> Path : \WebDevProject\scripts equests.php

> Warning: require(\WebDevProject\scripts equests.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevProject\userrequest.php on line 1

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '\WebDevProject\scripts equests.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevProject\userrequest.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevProject\userrequest.php on line 1

ANSWER:

`<?php $path = "\\WebDevProject\\scripts\\requests.php"; echo "Path : $path"; require $path;?>` Double \ to escape the slash, and needs a file include such as `<?php include ("scripts/userregister.php"); ?>`

Comment: Escape _all_ the backslashes in a double-quoted string, or you'll wind up with cases like this where the character following it causes it to be interpreted as an escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I have this, but the error is still happening.

`<?php $path = "\\WebDevProject\\scripts\\requests.php"; echo "Path : $path"; require $path;?>` The directory is right, I right clicked the file and "copy as path" and pasted it into the line above.

The file located at `"C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevProject\scripts\requests.php"` and being called from `"C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevProject\userrequest.php"`

Comment: Never mind, I forgot the include value.

Comment: Can you add your own answer and mark as resolved, if the problem is solved?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I do not see an option to mark as resolve sorry

Comment: "**Can you add your own answer** and mark as resolved "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $path = "\\WebDevProject\\scripts\\requests.php"; echo "Path : $path"; require $path;?>
```

Double \ to escape the slash, and needs a file include such as

```
<?php include ("scripts/userregister.php"); ?>
```